# How to change the height/alignment of specific letters – gender specific typography

Tags: typography

in my Master's Thesis I want to use a quite new method for gender specific words. I want to use the ¿-Symbol and would like to have the symbol starting on the base line, not like it does by default, on the descender line.

Here are screenshots of how it looks and how I wish it would look:

[image]
[image]

Does somebody know how to change the position of single letters or symbols?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Define it's function as a new unicode character:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{newunicodechar,graphicx}

\newunicodechar{¿}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{?}}

\begin{document}

Verbraucher¿nnen

\end{document}
```

Comment: works well, thank you!

Answer (score 7):

You can define `\?` for the purpose. The proposed macro raises the inverted question mark and rescales it to have the same height as an “i”. The dot is slightly smaller, though.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\DeclareRobustCommand\?{%
  \resizebox{!}{\fontcharht\font`i}{\raisebox{\depth}{¿}}%
}

\begin{document}

Verbraucher\?nnen

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

With `stackengine`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\DeclareRobustCommand\?{\abovebaseline[0pt]{¿}}
\begin{document}
Verbraucher\?nnen
\end{document}
```

[image]